# Search function for controls at run time

Tags: c#, winforms, search, tabcontrol

I have a tab control where I can add custom controls made from a button and a label underneath. I want to add a search function to my project so that when a user type a name of a control, it will show all controls where the name (label) starts with the letters typed. Also typing in a textbox will do the job..  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: It all depends on your app architecture and implemetation. You should at least give some code to show how you manage these custom controls, or try to create some kind of search and from then on you will get suggestion how to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done when adding the text to search in a textbox.

```
 private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        foreach (Control c in fl_panel.Controls)
        {              
            if (c.Name.ToUpper().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.ToUpper().ToString()) && textBox1.Text != "")
            {
                Control[] ctrls = fl_panel.Controls.Find(textBox1.Text.ToString(), true);
                c.Visible = true;  // to restore previous matches if I delete some text
            }

            else if(textBox1.Text == "")
            {
                c.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                c.Visible = false;
            }                      
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can search controls within parent control collection:

```
 foreach(Control c in ParentControl.Controls)
 {
      if(c.Name == "label1")
      {
         //add to your list
      }
 }
```

You can also check using `StartsWith("stringVal")`

```
     if(c.Name.StartsWith("l"))
     {
         //add to your list
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (Control control in this.Controls)
   {
      // Skip, if the control is the used TextBox
      if (control == textBox1) { continue; }

      // Show all controls where name starts with inputed string
      // (use ToLower(), so casing doesnt matter)
      if (control.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(textBox1.Text.Trim().ToLower()))
      {
         control.Visible = true;
      }

      // Hide objects that doesn't match
      else { control.Visible = false; }
   }
}
```

This toggles the controls' visibility, and hide's all items, that doesn't match the given input. Also casing doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this to find the controls that matches a text typed in the textbox, after that you can do whatever you want with it.

```
     private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {

    var controlMatchesCriteria = from c in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
            where c.Name == textBox1.Text
            select c;
}
```